# Can't import com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils via gradle

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gradle, android-studio

I tried to import `com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils` to my project in **Android Studio 0.5.4**.

I get this Gradle **Information** and **Error**:

```
Information:[C:\Users\Gast1_000\android studio projects\GeoPicture\app\build\exploded-aar\com.google.maps.android\android-maps-utils\0.3\AndroidManifest.xml:2, C:\Users\Gast1_000\android studio projects\GeoPicture\app\build\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\4.3.23\AndroidManifest.xml:3] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='8'> but library uses minSdkVersion='9'


Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.
```

**My build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.+'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3'
}
```

**Project Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I tried to change the minSdk version manually in the manifest of the maps-utils, but with each gradle sync it chnage it back.
Is there any other possiblility to add the library in AS 0.5.4?

Comment: Obviously you need to change your project to version 9 because something in the utils lib needs version 9. Changing the manifest of an external library is not a good idea usually.

Comment: You cannot just change the minSdkVersion of a library and hope it would work. You don't know what API and so they are using. So if you want to use the library, you will need to set your minSdkVersion to 9, because the library cannot work with 8.

Comment: my current minSDK version is 15

Comment: @TimRoes the library has minSDK 8 and the play Services has minSDK 9. I think there is the conflict bcause it depends on the play services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug at the moment: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/60

If Gradle overwrites you changes, just use Gradle to do these changes (as suggested in the above link) ;)

Add the following code block to your build file inside the android { .. } block.

```
applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
  variant.processManifest.doFirst {
    File manifestFile = file("${buildDir}/exploded-aar/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils/0.3/AndroidManifest.xml")
    if (manifestFile.exists()) {
      String content = manifestFile.getText('UTF-8')
      content = content.replaceAll(/minSdkVersion="8"/, 'minSdkVersion=\"9\"')
      manifestFile.write(content, 'UTF-8')
    }
  }
}
```

This of course isn't the best solution, but should do it until the bug is fixed:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66109 (Ignore minSdkVersions when matching libraries)